# php script giving error unexpected end of file

Tags: php

can any body tell why this script is giving

```
    <?php 
      session_start();
      $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "QSTNS");
          if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();

              $res = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qstns');
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

              $scoreis = 0;



              for ($i = 0; $i < $row[0]; $i++) {
                  $scoreis = $scoreis + $_SESSION['scr'][$i];
              }

              echo $scoreis;

              mysqli_close($con);                               
?>
```

error is  :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\quiiz_portal\scoreis.php on line 32

Comment: you forgot closing this tag:  `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { `

Comment: in this part of the code the closing "}" for the if (mysqli_connect_errno()) is missing

Comment: I formatted your code, for future reference, doing so will show these sorts of issues. Don't write php in a text editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to close the `}` after `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {` try this  :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "QSTNS");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$res = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qstns');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

$scoreis = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $row[0]; $i++) {
    $scoreis = $scoreis + $_SESSION['scr'][$i];
}

echo $scoreis;

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
```

has no matching brace, You need to say where the if ends